# Extract c# class to separate dll in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Im wondering if anyone knows of a quick way in Visual Studio 2010, or an existing Add-In that would allow me to quickly extract a class from one project (WPF or WinForms) and move it to a class library project while updating all references to the class in the original project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resharper can do that.  Don't know a free one off the top of my head.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Move_to_Folder

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Move_Type_to_Another_File_or_Namespace

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have JustCode installed and it has a move to Namespace as well, works great